# Slice Dataframe on custom condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have following Dataframe in R.

```
unique Id      Zone      Part
P-1            KRT       AS,RT
P-1            AFR       AS,RT
P-2            KRT       AS,RT
P-2            KRT       AS,RT
P-2            KRT       AS,RT 
P-3            RGT       
P-4            RGT       
P-4            RGT       
P-5            
P-6            NA        NA
```

I want to slice the datafrme where `Zone` and `Part` both are either blank or NA. Also for a given unique Id if `Zone` is `RGT` and `Part` is Blank or NA.

Required DF<-

```
unique ID       Zone     Part
P-3            RGT      
P-5            
P-6            NA        NA
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is meant by `for a given unique id`? A zone can have value `RGT` either `yes` or `no`?  What is its relation with unique id?  Also why P4 rows are not in output?

Comment: Can you post sample data **in `dput` format**? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question:

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- tibble::tribble(~unique_Id,      ~Zone,      ~Part,
                       "P-1"     ,      "KRT" ,      "AS,RT",
                       "P-1"     ,      "AFR" ,      "AS,RT",
                       "P-2"     ,      "KRT" ,      "AS,RT",
                       "P-2"     ,      "KRT" ,      "AS,RT",
                       "P-2"     ,      "KRT" ,      "AS,RT",
                       "P-3"     ,      "RGT" ,      "",
                       "P-4"     ,      "RGT" ,      "",
                       "P-4"     ,      "RGT" ,      "",
                       "P-5"     ,      "", "",
                       "P-6"     ,      NA    ,    NA)

dat %>% 
  group_by(unique_Id) %>%
  filter((Zone %in% c("", NA) & Part %in% c("", NA)) | (Zone == "RGT" & Part %in% c("", NA) & n() == 1)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  unique_Id Zone  Part 
  <chr>     <chr> <chr>
1 P-3       "RGT" ""   
2 P-5       ""    ""   
3 P-6       NA    NA
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I pass other attributes as well to filter, For Example If I want to `AFR` as well.

Comment: If you want both RGT and AFR in the Zone variable, change from `Zone == "RGT"` to `Zone %in% c("RGT", "AFR")`

Answer (score 1):

Without further info it's difficult to figure out exactly what will/won't solve your problem, but this might be a good starting point:

```
library(tidyverse)
test_dataframe <- tibble::tribble(
    ~unique.Id, ~Zone, ~Part,
  "P-1",            "KRT",       "AS,RT",
  "P-1",            "AFR",       "AS,RT",
  "P-2",            "KRT",       "AS,RT",
  "P-2",            "KRT",       "AS,RT",
  "P-2",            "KRT",       "AS,RT",
  "P-3",            "RGT",        NA,
  "P-4",             NA,         "RGT",
  "P-4",             NA,         "RGT",
  "P-5",             NA,          NA,
  "P-6",             NA,          NA
  )
test_dataframe %>%
  filter(Zone == "RGT" | is.na(Zone) & is.na(Part)) 
#>  unique.Id Zone  Part 
#>  <chr>     <chr> <chr>
#>1 P-3       RGT   NA   
#>2 P-5       NA    NA   
#>3 P-6       NA    NA
```